# ¿Por qué me marca stackoverflow aquí?

Tags: recursión

Estoy intentando hacer recursión pero me sigue marcando este error, ¿Cómo podría corregirle? El código tiene que imprimir una serie de números empezando en el 2 hasta el 25, donde primero se suman dos a 0, después a dos se suma tres, y así continuamente de tal manera que
2,5,7,10,12,15,17,20,22,25. Gracias y Saludos

```
public class Practica_examen_2 {
public static int masDos(int n) {
    if(n==0) {
        System.out.println(masDos(n+2));
        return masDos(n+2);
    }else {
        System.out.println(masTres(n+3));
        return masTres(n+3);
    }
}
public static int masTres(int n) {
    if(n%5!=0) {
        System.out.println(masDos(n+2));
        return masDos(n+2);
    }else {
        System.out.println(masTres(n+3));
        return masTres(n+3);
    }
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int inicio=0;
masDos(inicio);

}
```

}

Comment: ¿Puedes ser un poco más claro? Tu Código te devuelve un error o en algún punto colapsa y no funciona.

Por favor revisa el Recorrido de StackOverFlow (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para resolver dudas de como preguntar

Comment: Que lenguaje    ....

Comment: Buenas
Ya se resolvió el problema, aquí adjunto el códigopackage Practica_Examen;


public class Practica_examen {
public static int masDos(int n){
 if(n==25) {
  return 25;
 }else {
  System.out.println(n+3);
  return masTres(n+3);
 }
}
public static int masTres(int n) {
 if(n==25) {
  return 25;
 }else {
  System.out.println(n+2);
  return masDos(n+2);
 }
 }
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
int inicio=2;
System.out.println(inicio);
if(masDos(inicio)==25) {
 System.out.println("");
}
 }
}